# Is there a way to not start the spring boot application depending on the active profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I would like to know if there was a way to not start the spring boot application depending on the active profile. The reason for this is, I  have two profiles: local, and integration. When the profile is local, then I would start the application locally. If the profile is integration, I would like the test to not start the application, but rather just use the endpoints I've set in the configuration class so that it would actually use the deployed spring boot application.

```
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(
                initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class,
                classes = TestConfiguration.class,
                loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class
        ),
        @ContextConfiguration(
                initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class,
                classes = Application.class,
                loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class
        ),
    }
)
public class SpringContextConfiguration {

    @Before
    public void init(){}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do that. There shouldn't be a "deployed application", unless you're doing acceptance testing. The integration tests should set up their own test environment, allowing parallel development/testing to happen as well.

Comment: Don't. Write seperate tests for this, or just manually start the thing locally before kicking of your tests (or let your build script do this).

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, you can use `@Profile` annotation. You can just define two `@Beans` implementing `Foo` interface that only get created on startup and inject them into `Bar` which is only created in your `don't start profile`.

```
@Profile('dont')
@Bean
class Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

interface Foo {

}

@Bean
@Profile('dont')
class Foo1 implements Foo {

}

@Bean
@Profile('dont')
class Foo2 implements Foo {

}
```

This will lead to an ambiguity that will stop your application from starting up when profile `dont` is set.

Comment: That'll also prevent anything else from happening, such as running tests.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried applying your suggestion. While the application did in fact not start, the test failed because Spring threw an error. Is there a way of catching this error so the test would still proceed?

@Kayaman - Yes indeed. That's what exactly happened.

Comment: @Ryan just do it correctly. You'll never make it work with "don't start Spring, but run the tests anyway". The tests are still part of Spring, so you're going to waste a lot of time on this if you think your idea will work.

Comment: @Kayaman - Yes. This is what I sort of figured out too. I'll probably end up with two test runners, one for local, and one for integration. Each test runner would have different context configuration. Many thanks anyways!